# While consuming REST services created in Spring boot in Android is throwing the following error

Tags: android, spring

I have a rest service created in spring boot

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

@Autowired
private UserDao uDao;

@RequestMapping("/userDetails")
public List<UsersModel> showUserDetails() {
    List<UsersModel> users = uDao.getUserDetails();
    System.out.println("received");
    return users;
}

@GetMapping("/getName")
public String getUserName() {
    return "Das Lima";
}

 }
```

When calling in browser like `http://localhost:2020/SpringBootDemo/getName`
   it is returning fine and displaying the value "Das Lima". I don't know why its not working in android

But When tried to consume in android in AsyncTask like below

```
   private class UserAunthetication extends AsyncTask<String, String,   String>  {
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        final String url = "http://myIpAddress:2020/SpringBootDemo  /userDetails";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        Object usersModel = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

        return usersModel.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginPageActivity.this, "Inside post method " +  value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Encountered with problem like

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token

Comment: `http://myIpAddress:2020/SpringBootDemo  /userDetails` why there are blank spaces after SpringBootDemo ?

Comment: I think extra spaces were added, while copying and pasting the code on this place. There is no space in my coding

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its having an error parsing your json - I would wager the list of users isnt being returned as a valid json string from your showUserDetails method. To test out this just return "das lima" from your /userDetails endpoint as well, and i'd imagine it should work fine.